# Uploading video from website backend to YouTube

Tags: php, api, zend-framework, youtube, gdata

I am doing a site in cakephp where users can upload videos and those get published on the site once approved by the moderator. Currently, I am accepting video files which are being uploaded on my server. These files will be downloaded and checked by the moderator and if they seem fine the moderator will click a button that would upload the video to youtube and save a link to it in the database.

Now, I am using ClientLogin to authenticate with YouTube and trying to upload the video by using the Zend Gdata Libraries. There is not much documentation available on it and I am also not getting any error back, but its not working:

```
require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_YouTube');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_CLientLogin');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_App_Exception');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_App_AuthException');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoEntry');

// Define variables
$email = 'myemail@gmail.com';
$passwd = 'pass';
$applicationId = 'company-app-1.0';
$developerKey = 'AI39si5GGdQnX588uduNxgZL6I_UW32dr43FVH0ehf2jqN3CBIk5PIZHOG1-ag_Q8eaVlWnIxP7fLS3UW5Ofg45MzAxmW4XyAFw';

// Creating a ClientLogin authenticated Http Client
try {
    $client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($email, $passwd, 'cl');
} catch (Zend_Gdata_App_CaptchaRequiredException $cre) {
    echo 'URL of CAPTCHA image: ' . $cre->getCaptchaUrl() . "\n";
    echo 'Token ID: ' . $cre->getCaptchaToken() . "\n";
} catch (Zend_Gdata_App_AuthException $ae) {
    echo 'Problem authenticating: ' . $ae->exception() . "\n";
}

// Passing a Developer Key and ClientID to Zend_Gdata_YouTube
$yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube($client, $applicationId, null, $developerKey);


// Uploading a video

$myVideoEntry = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoEntry();
$filesource = $yt->newMediaFileSource('001.mov');
$filesource->setContentType('video/quicktime');
$filesource->setSlug('001.mov');
$myVideoEntry->setMediaSource($filesource);
$myVideoEntry->setVideoTitle('My Test Movie');
$myVideoEntry->setVideoDescription('My Test Movie');

// Note that category must be a valid YouTube category !
$myVideoEntry->setVideoCategory('Comedy');

// Set keywords, note that this must be a comma separated string
// and that each keyword cannot contain whitespace
$myVideoEntry->SetVideoTags('baby, funny');

// Optionally set some developer tags
/*
$myVideoEntry->setVideoDeveloperTags(array('mydevelopertag', 'anotherdevelopertag'));
*/

// Set Video as Private
$myVideoEntry->setVideoPrivate();

// Upload URI for the currently authenticated user

$uploadUrl = 'http://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/feeds/app/default/uploads';


// Try to upload the video, catching a Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException
// if availableor just a regular Zend_Gdata_App_Exception
try {
    $newEntry = $yt->insertEntry($myVideoEntry, $uploadUrl, 'Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoEntry');
} catch (Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException $httpException) {
    echo $httpException->getRawResponseBody();
} catch (Zend_Gdata_App_Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

try {
    $control = $videoEntry->getControl();
} catch (Zend_Gdata_App_Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

if ($control instanceof Zend_Gdata_App_Extension_Control) {
    if ($control->getDraft() != null && $control->getDraft()->getText() == 'yes') {
        $state = $videoEntry->getVideoState();
        if ($state instanceof Zend_Gdata_YouTube_Extension_State) {
            print 'Upload status: ' . $state->getName() .' '. $state->getText();
        } else {
            print 'Not able to retrieve the video status information' .' yet. ' . "Please try again shortly.\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that is what i am not able to figure out... cause as i said, i am not getting any errors or any output.

Comment: i don't understand why people are giving me negative votes when my question is as straight-forward as it can be! anyways, my problem is solved. apparently, it was giving me a blank screen on my localserver but its working fine on the live server. also i had not changed the default in the uploadUrl to my username.

Comment: Yeah, I also don't understand the negative votes with no comments. +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

apparently, it was giving me a blank screen on my localserver but its working fine on the live server. also i had not changed the default in the uploadUrl to my username.